# Hide virtual buttons after they are shown again

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I found out, that I can hide the virtual buttons of an android phone with:

this.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);

But once the user makes them visible by swiping from the edge, they stay visible.

How can I hide them again after a moment ?

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

I start a new activity.
When this new activity is started I call this in the onCreate-Method to hide the actionbar and the virtual buttons:

this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

this.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);

Edit:

```
  @Override
  public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {

      if ((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0) {

             getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                           View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION 
                           | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
     } else {

     }
  }
```

Comment: Please give more information on your code.

Comment: edited my comment, hope this are enough information.

Comment: That feature is only available on Android 4.1 or Higher.

Answer (score 0):

This is what your doing:
https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation.html

This is what you also want to be doing:
https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/visibility.html

So basically, when you hide an item, you need to listen (check) whether it's been changed (Turned On/Off) and from there re-enable it. I would copy/paste the code, but it's in those links.

Comment: Thanks for the anwser, but I got one last question :
I registered the listener and he gets called, when I swipe in the virtual buttons, but the buttons won't hide again ...

@Override
public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
  if ((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0) {
  getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

Wrote it on top for better visibility

Comment: Did you create the listener for the object?

Comment: Yes
 I made a Log.d output for the console, so i knew, that the method got called